# Xkb names of brightness, volume control and standby functions

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've written a custom keyboard layout in `xkb` and I would like to incorporate volume and brightness control as well as the standby and maybe shutoff function into it so I don't have to reach for the highest row of keys when I want to change them. But I don't know the `xkb` names of these functions. Does someone know them so I can put them into my `xkb`-layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the *Xorg* keycodes you search are located in this file:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet
```

So in your case:

```bash
volume down      --> XF86AudioLowerVolume
volume up        --> XF86AudioRaiseVolume
brightness down  --> XF86MonBrightnessDown
brightness up    --> XF86MonBrightnessUp
standby          --> XF86Standby
```

Here is some [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_extension) if needed.

Hope this helps !